Limma - Voom function for microarray data
I am wondering if anyone can have a look at the voom plot I got below and let me know if this is indicative of an issue with my design?
I understand that it should be more of a J-shape rather than a straight line.
Any help is appreciated.
I am not sure if this is because its microarray data instead of RNA-SEQ count data?

You might be better off requesting migration to our sister Bioinformatics site

Hi, yeah that's where I posted originally but was asked to post here lol
